# Why was Banshee chosen to be the default for 11.04?

Tags: 11.04, banshee

What are the reasons for Banshee replacing Rhythmbox in Ubuntu 11.04?

I don't want your opinion on which is best nor why. I want to know what the reasoning was behind the decision.

Comment: I don't want your opinion on which is best and why. I want to know what the reasoning was behind the decision.

Comment: Bashee is more cool

Comment: Why not Audacious? It's definitely better than banshee or rythombox

Answer (score 20, accepted):

dv3500a's [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10911/why-is-banshee-becoming-the-default/10928#10928) has links to the information. Here is an [informative video](http://ubuntudevelopers.blip.tv/file/4363767/) from Gabriel Burt's talk at GUADEC that might give you some information that gives you an overview of some of the things that are nice in Banshee. Here are [the slides](http://download.banshee.fm/documents/2010-GUADEC-Banshee_Awesome_Factory.pdf).

I was at the session and here are some of the highlights:

- The ability to change UIs from netbook to "normal". (It's handy to have one media player for both form factors)
- A vibrant community of contributors (see the slides for numbers) who is willing to work with us closely.
- An easy way to hack on extensions.
- Follows the GNOME schedule.
- Polished device support, including syncing of playlists to devices.
- Video library support (though this is new and not very polished, maybe we'll hide it for 11.04)

Banshee has a bunch of other great [features](http://banshee.fm/features/), but these were the ones we mostly discussed at this session.

Comment: Laughing out loud, as Rhythmbox becomes default again.

Answer (score 8):

This was discussed and decided at [UDS-N](http://summit.ubuntu.com/uds-n/) on Friday 29th October at 10:00 AM. The blueprint for the default application selection [is on Launchpad](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/packageselection-desktop-n-application-selection). There hasn't yet been a video posted of the session on the [ubuntu developers channel](http://ubuntu.mirocommunity.org/listing/new/) but there may be in the future. You can also look at the [IRC log](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/524320/) for this session.

Comment: the blueprint does not state the reason(s).

Answer (score 1):

Banshee has more features, and more plugins (Amazon MP3 sotre, ebook , videos...) and it seems to be more user friendly, even if, today, it's often too buggy. Some reasons are in this blueprint of maverick: https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/desktop-maverick-desktop-application-selection (it has been used for natty discussions too) see in the whiteboard the ==Music Player== part

" [davidnielsen 2010-10-22]
Banshee 1.8.0 no longer depends on HAL, it has excellent integration with Ubuntu specific technologies such as the SoundMenu and Application Indicators. The development pace is nothing short of amazing and the community which has grown around Banshee has proven to be welcoming and swift to fix bugs. Banshee has multiple UIs which suits Ubuntu well for deployment on UNE as well as the desktop. "

Answer (score -1):

The cynic in me says:
Banshee is a better clone of iTunes than Rhythmbox and given the recent suggestion that Ubuntu 11.04 will have the global menu bar by default, it all makes for a better clone of OSX.

Comment: Thanks for voting my answer down.  Ultimately, any answers to this question will be subjective and opinionated.  It is just *my* opinion that music players like Rhythmbox and Banshee aim to be iTunes clones and my personal opinion is that iTunes is a terrible piece of software and not a good target to aim for.  There is no hate here, I am a diehard linux user and I own an iPod.  My answer was playing devil's advocate as much as anything.

Comment: This is not the place for opinions or discussion.

Comment: Agreed, perhaps the question should be marked subjective.

Comment: If your answer just said new users may find Banshee more familiar and therefore easier to use as it is similar to itunes. You might have got an upvote. (I didn't give you the downvote)

Comment: @JRT I am not asking for just anyones opinions. I want to know what reason the ubuntu team had in making this decision. As I can not find a published reason just a decision.

Comment: The question and its correct answer have subjectiveness to them. The asker wants to know the reason to changing to Banshee and there are multiple logs showing the discussion for the switch. You don't need to layer on your opinion.