# Why is ubuntu replacing Banshee with Rhythmbox in 12.04?

Tags: banshee, music, rhythmbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is Rhythmbox becoming the default (again)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75593/why-is-rhythmbox-becoming-the-default-again)

Is is because of mono thing?
Is it the GTK3 support thing?
Or i dont know...

What value Rhythmbox (replacing Banshee) adds to ubuntu 12.04.

I feel banshee has a far better interface than Rhythmbox. Why dont Rhythmbox just redo the interface.

BTW any good music player in market. Apart from tomahawk.