# Why was Rhythmbox replaced with Banshee?

Tags: banshee, rhythmbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is Banshee becoming the default?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10911/why-is-banshee-becoming-the-default)

What was the reason for this replacement?

Comment: Yeh, it should be closed as a duplicate